# Split tests with Minitest 5 in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm switching one of my projects to rails 4.1, which by default uses minitest version 5.

I also use minitest-rails 2.0.1 gem.

Before switching to minitest 5, in rails 4.0 when I ran rake test, it used to run model tests first, then controllers, etc...

Now with minitest 5 doesn't seem like this is happening.

Is there a way to keep that current option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has changed this behavior. It processes all test files in the same run to increase the speed. You can simulate the old behavior by running separate tasks with the following:

```
$ rake test:units test:controllers test:integration
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own rake tasks to run tests separately. Examples:

**Rails 5**

```
$ rails test:unit
$ rails test:system

lib/tasks/tests.rake

gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest'
require 'rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin'

namespace :test do
  task :system => "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    Minitest.rake_run(["test/system"])
  end

  task :unit => "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    Minitest.rake_run(FileList['test/*'].exclude('test/system'))
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake

**Rails 4** you can check out here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake